# htmlAgilityPack parse table to datatable or array

Tags: c#, linq, html-agility-pack

I have these tables:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><th>Header 1</th></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Header 1</th>
<th>Header 2</th>
<th>Header 3</th>
<th>Header 4</th>
<th>Header 5</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>text 1</td>
<td>text 2</td>
<td>text 3</td>
<td>text 4</td>
<td>text 5</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to transform into an array or List using this code:

```
var query = from table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table").Cast<HtmlNode>()
                         from row in table.SelectNodes("tr").Cast<HtmlNode>()
                         from header in row.SelectNodes("th").Cast<HtmlNode>()
                         from cell in row.SelectNodes("td").Cast<HtmlNode>()
                         select new { 
                             Table = table.Id, 
                             Row = row.InnerText, 
                             Header = header.InnerText,
                             CellText = cell.InnerText
                         };
```

But it doesn't work. What is wrong?

Comment: Why is it wrong? Show the exception or the result obtained so far.

Comment: Result view return: {" Value can not be null \ r \ nName make parameter : . Source" }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some notes:

- You do not need a cast
- you are assuming that each row have headers
- SelectNodes needs to receive an xpath and you are passing just names

if i were you i would use a foreach and model my data, that way i get to have more control and efficiency, but if you still want to do it your way this is how it should be

```
var query = from table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table")
            where table.Descendants("tr").Count() > 1 //make sure there are rows other than header row
            from row in table.SelectNodes(".//tr[position()>1]") //skip the header row
            from cell in row.SelectNodes("./td") 
            from header in table.SelectNodes(".//tr[1]/th") //select the header row cells which is the first tr
            select new
            {
              Table = table.Id,
              Row = row.InnerText,
              Header = header.InnerText,
              CellText = cell.InnerText
            };
```

Comment: How best to separate the data from this site ?

http://186.233.149.182/sisgol/DERW700B.asp?SelStart1=2015&SelStop1=2015&SelStart2=149&SelStop2=149&SelStart3=6&SelStop3=6&SelStart4=&SelStop4=&SelStart5=&SelStop5=&RunReport=Run+Report